# sqlalchemy: how to update many-to-many relation table with additional columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three tables: `Hero`, `Ability` and `HeroAbilityRelation`

Models are

```py
class Hero(Base):
    __tablename__ = "hero"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(16), unique=True, index=False, nullable=False)
    abilities = relationship(
        "Ability",
        secondary=HeroAbilityRelation,
        back_populates="heroes",
    )

class Ability(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ability"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(128), unique=True, index=False, nullable=False)
    heroes = relationship(
        "Hero",
        secondary=HeroAbilityRelation,
        back_populates="abilities",
    )

HeroAbilityRelation = Table(
    'hero_ability_relation',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('hero_id', Integer, ForeignKey('hero.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('ability_id', Integer, ForeignKey('ability.id'), primary_key=True),
    # I added this field
    Column('how_to_get', String(256), unique=True, index=True, nullable=True)
)
```

Many heroes may have many abilities.

Before I just had only `hero_id` and `ability_id` fields. So create relationship was simple:

```py
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
db = SessionLocal()

hero_record = model.Hero(name='Superman')
hero_record.abilities.extend(
  db.query.filter(model.Ability.id.in_([1,2,3])).all()
)
db.add(hero_record)
db.commit()
db.refresh(hero_record)
```

So `Superman` will be added and get three abilities with ids 1, 2, 3

If `Superman`'s `id` is `5` relation table will be looks like

| hero_id | ability_id |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

That was fine, but my new table has three columns, and I want to fill it like

| hero_id | ability_id | how_to_get |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | was bit by spider |
| 5 | 2 | got as Christmas present from mom |
| 5 | 3 | ... |

So, how can I update `how_to_get` field when adding new relations or creating new `Hero`?

Answer (score 0):

My own solution is:

```
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
db = SessionLocal()

hero_record = model.Hero(name='Superman')
db.add(hero_record)
db.commit()
db.refresh(hero_record)

abilities_data = [
  (1, "was bit by spider"),
  (2, "got as Christmas present from mom"),
  (3, "...")
]

try:
  db.execute(
    model.HeroAbilityRelation.insert(),
    [
      {
        'ability_id': id,
        'hero_id': hero_record.id,
        'how_to_get': desc
      } for id, desc in abilities_data
    ]
  )
except DatabaseError as e:
  db.rollback()
  db.delete(db.query(model.Hero).get(hero_record.id))
  raise e
finally:
  db.commit()

db.refresh(hero_record)
```

But here is some problems that I want to avoid:

1. I need to add `hero` into DB and commit transaction before adding relation records (to get `ID` of new record) instead of direct `extend()` method.
2. Because of point 1, I need to handle error and delete `hero` manually (I don't want to add new record in case of relation adding errors)
3. Because of point 1, number of commits increased to two instead one

So any one-commit suggestions are welcome

<sub>Memo: to solve three problems above [`session.begin()` and `nested_session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint) may be used.</sub>